# Global site variables to be used in node fields and menu item

Tags: 7

I'm looking for some way of having variable defined by admin which can be displayed in some fields or nodes.

Real use case:
I have that specific date that changes periodically. And I want it to appear in some places, ie. within text of some node body (with possibility of fixing the variable ie. putting some text instead of date, but it's not a matter of my question).

My guess: create some hook to preg_replace all occurences of some string, ie. ##VAR_VARNAME1## with certain fields of nodes or within field texts. But actually I know that it will occur mainly in 2 or 3 places within my website (which is for sure body of one specific node and text of 1 menu item).

Any ideas to make this efficient and quick?

edit: I believe it's easy to do with defining new block.. but how about way I mentioned above..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [Custom Tokens](https://www.drupal.org/project/token_custom) extension to the [token](http://drupal.org/project/token) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... gives the user the ability to create custom tokens for specific replacements that can improve other modules relying on the Drupal 7 token API or, for Drupal 6, the Token module.
>
> Versions 7.x-1.x and previours relied on PHP evaluation to build custom tokens.
>
> The new 7.x-2.x relies on input filters. While still allowing for PHP tokens through the D7 core PHP filter module, administrators can permit only HTML or plain text custom tokens.

Comment: Not bad! Actually now I see that I can just extend my module and allow to use new tokens this way. Probably more important is now to find way of using tokens within menu items or nodes (token_replace function). Thank you.

Comment: No problem, glad to help! Would this work for tokens in menus? http://drupal.org/project/menu_token

Comment: I saw that too, but since I'd already overriden default menu items (to more generic markup with text and multiple links) I guess I need to do this by my own. Nevertheless - thanks, enjoy your day :)